# Using sessions in async in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, c#-5.0

This is the code i tried but the current http context goes null
HttpContext.current.Session[] goes null in between code execution.
async Methods are as follows

```
      public async Task<User> GetUser()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_sessionService.IsSet(SessionKey.User))
            {
                return _sessionService.Get<GBLUser>(SessionKey.User);
            }
            else
            {
                var userID = _environmentService.GetUserId();
                var user = await _userService.GetUser(userID);
                _sessionService.Set(SessionKey.User, user);
                return user;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("", ex);
        }
    }
 public void Set(SessionKey key, object data)
    {
        try
        {
            var sessionData = (Dictionary<string, object>)HttpContext.Current.Session[_sessionKey];
            if (sessionData != null)
            {
                sessionData.Add(key.ToString(), data);
                HttpContext.Current.Session[_sessionKey] = sessionData;
            }
            else
            {
              HttpContext.Current.Session[_sessionKey] = new Dictionary<string, object> { {                         key.ToString(), data } };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Is there any other configuration required to make this work

Comment: In your `web.config`, what is the value of `httpRuntime@targetFramework`?

Comment: Are you starting work on the thread-pool?

Comment: @ Stephen Cleary 4.5

Comment: @StephenCleary any Settings to be changed in webconfig

Comment: @samrodrigues: No, that's what it should be. Could you set a breakpoint immediately before the `await` and see what type `SynchronizationContext.Current` is?

Comment: @StephenCleary  System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in between code execution"?

Comment: @StephenCleary between two async calls the session variable goes null

Comment: @samrodrigues: Same request?

Comment: @StephenCleary: Yes. For the same request.

Comment: @samrodrigues: In that case, I would raise the issue with Microsoft Support.